# CakePHP setFlash when logged in

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I show a flash message using CakePHP when a user has successfully logged in (either manually or via a redirect). So for example 'Welcome back!'

I can't just add it to the `login()` method as that will just show it on the login page and NOT when a user has **sucessfully** logged in.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://labs.iamkoa.net/2008/01/13/session-based-flash-messages-look-better-cakephp/) shows how you can use session based flash messages with CakePHP. The [Cake Session API](http://book.cakephp.org/view/322/The-Cake-Session-Component) may be helpful as well.

Comment: I know how to create session flash messages with CakePHP. The problem I have is how to show one when a user has logged in as you can't attach it to the method like normal!

Answer (score -2):

To be honest, I have no idea how that CakePHP-thing works. But you might wanna try to save a session-variable when the user has successfully logged in (still at the login-page). Then you (already did) redirect him to your success-page and load the session-variable, noticing that you need to `setFlash`.
*Don't forget to unset the session-variable!*